# How to concatenate lines from 3 files to form a single line

Tags: shell, awk

```
echo " Student1 " > log1.txt
echo " Marks " > log2.txt
echo " Percentage " > log3.txt

cat log1.txt log2.txt log3.txt > final.txt 
Student1
Marks
Percentage
```

Which gives me the above output but I need to print the output in single line like below. Please help ?

```
Student1 Marks Percentage
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't care about white space, this is the job `paste` was invented to do:

```
$ paste log?.txt
 Student1        Marks   Percentage
```

If you need to just have 1 space between each field and no leading space:

```
$ echo $(cat log?.txt)
Student1 Marks Percentage

$ echo $(paste log?.txt)
Student1 Marks Percentage

$ awk '{ORS=(FILENAME==ARGV[ARGC-1]?RS:FS); $1=$1}1' log?.txt
Student1 Marks Percentage
```

or with GNU awk for ARGIND:

```
$ awk '{ORS=(ARGIND<(ARGC-1)?FS:RS); $1=$1}1' log?.txt
Student1 Marks Percentage
```

This looks like an attempt to create the header line for some terrible text processing shell script, though - if so I'd strongly recommend that you stop and ask for direction so we can show you how to write the whole thing in awk. Shell is an environment from which to call tools with a language to sequence those tools, that's all. The tool that shell calls to manipulate text is awk.

Comment: Nicely done; it's worth noting that the `paste` solution is the only one that works with _multi-line_ input files.

Answer (score 2):

Since you've conveniently put trailing spaces in the files:

```
{ cat log1.txt log2.txt log3.txt | tr -d \\n; echo; }
```

will do nicely.  The trailing echo adds a trailing newline, which you may or may not want.  Or you can use awk, which nicely omits the trailing space on log3.txt (and adds spaces if the files do not actually have a trailing space):

```
cat log[123].txt | awk '{$1=$1}1' RS= OFS=' '
```

Comment: That's sheer beauty :)

Comment: { cat log1.txt log2.txt log3.txt | tr -d \\n; echo; }
StudentMarksSuccess

Comment: can you suggest how to include spaces in between

Comment: Spaces are already there and I am getting exactly what you are looking for Could you check your file contents if it has the proper spacing especially log2.txt and log3.txt

Comment: If the files have trailing spaces as indicated in the question, that should not be necessary.